# Angular : Fetch new data after change

Tags: angular, rest

I have a service which sends HTTP requests to my API with two methods: one that fetches data, and another one that updates objects after a click event.

My initial data is stored upon call on `ngOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.myservice.getData();
}
```

A method is called when a button is clicked :

```
update(id) {
    this.myservice.update(id);    
}
```

This works fine, but when I click the update method I need to refresh the page to see my data with the new updated value.
I'm fairly new to Angular and I want to know how to approach this. I tried re-fetching data inside the update function after the update call, but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried returning the updated data when calling `this.myservice.update(id);` and re-assigning it to `this.data`? Like `this.data = this.myservice.update(id);`

Comment: Basicaly you do not need two functions `getData()` and  `update()`, just use the same code `this.data = this.myservice.getData();` in `update()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subject wrapped observable and subscribe to any it if any changes occurs. Should any change occur, the callback function will re grab data to update the list.

in your service

```
dataChangesSubject = new Subject<any>();
```

Then modify the function (i'm assuming there's data declared in your service)

in your service update function add at the end of it

```
      this.dataChangesSubject.next(this.data);
```

in your component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myservice.dataChangesSubject.
    subscribe((data) => this.data = data;
    )
  this.data = this.myservice.getData();
}
```

---

alternatively, you can just have the observable return no data, and do whatever code you do to update your list.
So in your service, still declare subject

```
dataChangesSubject = new Subject<void>();
```

in your service update function, just notify of change.

```
this.dataChangesSubject.next();
```

Then in your component, add whatever code you do to get latest data in callback function of next

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myservice.dataChangesSubject.
    subscribe(() => {
      //code goes here 
      this.data = this.myservice.getData();
      }
    )
  this.data = this.myservice.getData();
}
```

Comment: My update function inside my service class does not return the data just a message of success or failure.

Comment: @mockingbid, doesn't make a difference what it returns. If you subscribe to a subject, you can add a line whenever there's an update call `<observable/subject>.next(<data>)` on that subject, and emit the data so all subscribers get it

Comment: Sorry but i didn't quite understand you. I have two method getData which returns a response object then subscribe in my component to assign my items to data using `this.myservice.getData().subscribe(data => { this.items = data)` inside my ngOninit . My update method sends a post request and returns an object Response containing a message. in `this.dataChangesSubject.next(this.data)` this.data corresponds to what ?`

Comment: @mockingbid, I added a second example in case you don't have any data inside your service. the bottom line, when your service gets called to update, then it'll notify all component that it updates. In your component, you can subscribe, and call code in a callback function (see curly brackets) to get data gain

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your "data" variable with new updated id. Just do `this.data = this.myservice.getData();` after calling the update method. That's why you see it fine when you reload the page. You're calling it on the ngOnInit

Comment: I tried this, but i have to click the button twice to see the item goes away ?

Comment: No, you don't. Just click the button and that's it. If that doesn't work, maybe you'll have to make your function return an observable and subscribe to wait for the return. =)